# How to assign a specific group to a Sharepoint page within a site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, office-365-groups, sharepoint-permissions

I have a lot of people that use a Sharepoint website and we only want specific groups to have edit rights to specific pages. We have our groups created, but when we add them to the site, it adds them to the whole site to be able to edit everything and not just a specific page, per group. Basically, specific groups will have edit permissions on specific pages. Whereas the Owners have full control over all pages.

Answer (score 0):

Pages are stored in libraries, and like any other regular libraries read-only permission can be granted to the entire library as well to individual pages.

Steps:

1. Site Settings -> Site Content
2. Site Pages Library if the page is in this library or Pages library
3. Gear Icon -> Library Settings
4. Permission for this document library
5. Stop inheriting permission
6. Grant specific group read permission to the library
7. Grant read only permission to specific page by selecting the page and then Manage Access

Here is [an article](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-prevent-team-site-members-from-editing-sharepoint-pages/) showing details how to accomplish this.

[MS Document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782) showing how to customize permissions for a SharePoint list or library